Using Python, can one convert a .tiff file to a .gpkg file, such that all raster cells are indiscriminatorily kept?
I would like to convert a .tiff file into a .gpkg file, such that every raster cell is accounted for.
When I convert my .tiff to an image array with numpy, I get a value of 350403 returned for the length.
When I attempt the same using gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(img_src), I get a value of 343003.
Is there a way that I can ensure that the GeoDataFrame is going to keep all the cells/pixels?
Here is my code, I apologize that it is not  the best.
def tiff_to_csv(tiff_file: str, csv_file: str):
'''

Description:

    - This function converts a TIFF file to a CSV file.

Parameters:

        tiff_file:
            - the path to the TIFF file to be converted

        csv_file:
            - the path to save the CSV file

Returns:

            None

'''



# Open the TIFF file
tif_image = Image.open(tiff_file)

# Convert my image to a numpy array
image_array = np.array(tif_image)

# Flatten the array to convert it to a 1D vector
vector_data = image_array.flatten()

print(len(vector_data))

# Save the pixel values to a CSV file
np.savetxt(csv_file, vector_data, delimiter=",")

with rasterio.open(tiff_file) as src:
    
    band1 = src.read(1)
    
    no_data = src.nodata
    print(f'no_data: {no_data}')

    # Generate shapes  (polygons)  from the raster values,
    results = (
        {'properties': {'raster_val': v}, 'geometry': shape(s)}
        for i, (s, v) in enumerate(shapes(band1, transform=src.transform))
    )

    # Convert my shapes to a GeoDataFrame
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(band1)
    total_shapes = len(gdf)
    print(f"Number of shapes (including nodata): {total_shapes}")

Interestingly, there are no 'no_data' values, but there is definitely a mismatch in length outputs.

The first step in debugging this is going to be examining properties like src.width, .height, .crs, .transform, .count, .indexes. Next step will be comparing the OP code with example code, such as: for geom, val in rasterio.features.shapes(mask, transform=dataset.transform):, geom = rasterio.warp.transform_geom(dataset.crs, 'EPSG:4326', geom, precision=6). I'm worried that your source and your destination datasets are imposing different flat projections upon a famously spherical Earth. See also the quickstart.

If you're expecting rasterio.features.shapes() to produce one polygon per cell then you misunderstand how that works and should consult the docs

The code you've posted also contains errors that would prevent it from running.  Namely results is never used and from_features will not accept an array.  I assume you've fixed these things but it would help if you updated your question

When you vectorize with rasterio, adjacent pixels with the same values get dissolved into one polygon, that's why you get fewer polygons than raster pixels.
You can add a random float between 0 and 1 to each value in the raster array, to make each pixel value unique (hopefully, unless you are very unlucky), then vectorize into a Geopandas dataframe, and floor the values back to the original values:
import rasterio
from rasterio.features import shapes
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np

raster_file = r"C:\Users\bera\Desktop\gistest\random_raster.tif"

#Vectorize the raster into a Geopandas dataframe
with rasterio.open(raster_file) as src:
    array = src.read(1)
    print(array.shape)
    #(26, 33). There are 858 pixels in my raster
    results = (
      {'properties': {'raster_val': v}, 'geometry': s}
      for i, (s, v) in enumerate(shapes(source=array, mask=None, transform=src.transform)))
    geoms  = list(results)
    df = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(geoms)

print(df.shape)
#(679, 2)
#So 26*33 - 679 = 179 cells are missing
df.to_file(r"C:\gistest\vectorized.gpkg")

#Add a random float between 0-1 to each array vaklue
random_floats = np.random.rand(*array.shape)
array_with_random_decimals = (array + random_floats).astype("float32")

#Vectorize
results = (
      {'properties': {'raster_val': v}, 'geometry': s}
      for i, (s, v) in enumerate(shapes(source=array_with_random_decimals, mask=None, transform=src.transform)))
geoms  = list(results)
df2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(geoms)

df2.shape[0]
#858. Which equals the number of values in the input raster.
#Floor the values back to the original values
df2["raster_val"] = np.floor(df2["raster_val"])
df2.to_file(r"C:\gistest\vectorized_with_random_addition.gpkg")


